# how to implement code for swapping the images?

Tags: iphone, ios4

hi all how to implement code for swapping the images if a row consists 10 images whenever we want swap the image by selecting the image clicking on that so help me to solve the problem in iphone

Comment: actually i have taken 10 custom buttons in a single row then appended images to the custom buttons. Now i have to swap images how it is possible in iphone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asuming that images are in scrollview

1. First of all set image on uibutton and add target to that button to handle button click.
2. on button click set content offset of scrollview like this

`[scrollview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(btn.frame.origin.x, 0) animated:YES];`